# How do I learn what my enemies' powers do?

Tags: tales-of-maj-eyal

I play a lot of [ToME 4](http://te4.org/), and it's awesome. But there's something I've not managed to figure out. When your character is under the influence of an effect (e.g. 'confused'), you can see that clearly as an icon in the status panel, and when hovering the mouse you get a detailed description of what the effect is doing.

If you `look` at an enemy, similarly you get a nice popup summary detailing that enemy's stats, resistances, and the abilities/effects currently in place on that enemy (e.g. 'Frenzy, Carbon Spikes'). I'd often like to know more about exactly how unpleasant these abilities are going to be for me! However, I can't find any way to get an explanation of those effects, since moving the mouse after doing a `look` collapses the popup.

Is there any way to view the detailed information about an effect which is present on an enemy?

Answer (score 3):

Right click the creature and select the option "Inspect creature". Active buffs and debuffs are under "general" tab while all their talents are under the "Talents" tab